# Is this set a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I am studying Ring Theory for the first time in my life- so the following question may be a very silly one. While trying to solve an (unrelated) exercise, this question clicked in me, and it has been bugging me since then. The idea is, if a general set *can be compared to* a ring, then whether it is indeed a ring or not. Formally framed,

> Let us have a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ and a set $S$ equipped with two operations defined on it, namely $\oplus$ and $\odot$. We also have a bijection $f:R\to S$ which satisfies the two following properties-
>
> 1. $f(x+y)=f(x)\oplus f(y)$
> 2. $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\odot f(y)$
>
> Is $S$ also a ring?

The first thing that pops up on a closer inspection is that the way the question is framed immediately adds closure of the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ to the hypothesis. This is because without these operations being closed, the RHS of the two properties wont make any sense. So, the first question is, can we loosen the hypothesis up a little bit more, or frame it in a little more different way so that closure is no longer required for the very definitions to make sense (although it may be implied- afterall, that's what we want)$^*$.

The next question is whether $S$ is indeed a ring or not. If it isn't, then what is the minimum amount of information that has to added to the hypothesis for $S$ to be a ring? If it is, then can we trim some information off from the original formulation, and still keep it true?

If we interpret an isomorphism as a relabelling, it intuitively looks like $S$ should be a ring. But, the relabelling analogy only works when the ring structure of $S$ is given a priori. So, it's hard to say whether it will still work where the structure of $S$ is not immediately evident.

I'm sorry if the question sounds a little vague- I tried my best to make it as formal as I could. Also, feel free to edit the title if you can find something more suitable.

---

$*$ One thing I should add here which I had in mind but forgot to mention is my answer to Thorgott's comment. Instead of defining the operations from $S\times S\to S$, I planned to define them from $S\times S\to S^\prime \supset S$ so as not to force the closedness, and see whether it follows only from the axioms of $R$ and $f$.

Comment: Being "closed" under an operation is a bad notion. You should axiomatize  the operation as a map $S\times S\rightarrow S$, and then "closedness" is superfluous. You have not addressed so far whether rings are supposed to have multiplicative units or not. A slightly more general set-up is to not even require $R$ to be a ring, but just for it to have two operations as well. Then it turns out that $R$ is a ring (without unit) *if and only if* $S$ is, and $R$ has a unit if and only $S$ does. Simply check $f$ identifies the corresponding sets of axioms.

Comment: $(S,\oplus,\odot)$ is actually the same mathematical "thing" as $(R,+,\cdot)$. It is only a matter of changing names. Set $R$ gets the new name $S$.  Element $x$ in $R$ gets the new name $f(x)$. Operations $+$ and $\cdot$ get the new names $\oplus$ and  $\odot$. This is the essence of "isomorphic" and structure $(S,\oplus,\odot)$ has the same mathematical properties as structure $(R,+,\cdot)$.

Comment: @Thorgott my idea was to define the operations $S\times S\to S^/ \supset S$ so that closedness is not forced. What's your opinion in that case?

Comment: @drhab I do understand that a ring isomorphism is basically a relabelling. But, this case is slightly different- here we have a ring, and *some sort of* relabelling, and we want to ask whether the relabelling still preserves the structure. Intuitively, the answer of course looks like an "yes" (and I initially planned to include that in the post, but later, I forgot), but we still can't be very sure, can we?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, that's a very unnatural thing to do.

Comment: @SayanDutta The properties of $f$ guarantee that $(S,\oplus,\odot)$ is a ring. 

E.g. we have associativity of $\oplus$ because: $$u\oplus (v\oplus w)=f(x)\oplus(f(y)\oplus f(z))=f(x)\oplus f(y+z)=f(x+(y+z))=$$$$f((x+y)+z)=f(x+y)\oplus f(z)=(f(x)\oplus f(y))\oplus f(z)=(u\oplus v)\oplus w$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $f$ that you defined, a priori, can only be a set-theoretic bijection $R\to S$,  because even if you named two operations on $S$, we don't know the structure of $S$ (you didn't give axioms to define how the operations work on $S$).

This situation could be what you were thinking about: suppose that you have a ring $(R,\cdot,+,1_R,0_R)$ and a set $S$. If $f:S\to R$ is a bijection (viewing $R$ as a set), we can actually give $S$ the structure of a ring. We can define the ring $(S,\otimes,\oplus,1_S,0_S)$ like follows ($s,s'\in S$):

$s\otimes s'$ is the (unique because $f$ is bijective) element $t\in S$ such that $f(t)=f(s)\cdot f(s')$; similarly, $s\oplus s'$ is the element $t\in S$ such that $f(t)=f(s)+ f(s')$; and obviously $0_S:=f(0_R)$ and $1_S:=f(1_R)$.

You may verify that, with this definition for the operations, $S$ is a ring. For example, let us verify the distributive property; we will denote with $t_r$, for any $r\in R$, the element of $S$ for which $f(t_r)=r$.  $$s_1\otimes(s_2\oplus s_3)=t_{f(s_1)\cdot f(s_2\oplus s_3)}=t_{f(s_1)\cdot f(t_{f(s_2)+f(s_3)})}=t_{f(s_1)\cdot (f(s_2)+f(s_3))}=t_{(f(s_1)\cdot f(s_2))+(f(s_1)\cdot f(s_3))}$$ $$=t_{f(s_1)\cdot f(s_2)}\oplus t_{f(s_1)\cdot f(s_3)}=(s_1\otimes s_2)\oplus(s_1\otimes s_3).$$ (Justifying all the equalities may seem confusing at first, but they are all immediate from the definitons and the distributivity of $R$).

PS: notice that $f$ must be defined $S\to R$, and not viceversa; intuitively, you can convince yourself that it is the right direction thinking that $S$ can be given a ring structure if it can be "inserted" in a ring (in fact the hypothesis of $f$ surjective could be replaced with a weaker one, while the injectivity is fundamental).

Comment: i.e. [transport the ring structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure) along the bijection $\,f\ \ $

Comment: That's a nice answer (+1)! But, can you please elaborate a little on why $f$ has to defined $S\to R$ and not vice versa?

Comment: @BillDubuque you *really* love that thing, don't you :)

Comment: Also, please check the edit and my comments below the main post.

Comment: If you have a map $f:S\to R$, in order for the argument used in my answer to hold, you need that $f$ is injective and that $\operatorname{Im}f$ is a subring of $R$. If you have a map $g:R\to S$ instead, unless it is a bijection (that is the same as a bijection $S\to R$ indeed), you don't have enough data to define on $S$ a ring structure. Just think if there are two elements $s,s'\in S$ not in the image of $g$; how would you define $s+s'$ for example?

Comment: I don't understand well what you have in mind in your comments, but I believe that your idea of closedness has to do with the condition that $\operatorname{Im}f\subseteq R$ is a subring